Finding the Pseudoinverse and Least Squares Solution for an Unknown Rank-1 3x3 Matrix
I'm studying for a linear algebra final, and I came across this exercise in a past exam. I'm not sure how to tackle it. I thought that given that Nul(A) is orthogonal to Row(A), I could find a vector V that is orthogonal to [2,1,2]^T, but I got stuck....
Maybe it has something to do with SVD?
I really hope you can give me a hand. Thanks!

Given $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3} \ $ as a rank 1 matrix such that $ \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} $ belongs to the row space of  A  and:
$$ A \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}  $$

Find the pseudoinverse of $A$:  $ A^+ $
Use the pseudoinverse to determine the solution of least squares of minimum norm of the equation $$ A \cdot x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

